# Blank Azure Blobs with Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to simply download an excel blob from Azure Storage, make some modifications and then upload it with a new name using Azure Python SDK v12. I've found several questions on here using v2.x with blockblobservice module. But that is not available in v12. An additional constraint is that I do not want anything locally as this is part of a serverless app.

Here is my code and notations:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import io
import pandas as pd

#Download Blob: works fine
download_client=BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=az_str, 
        container_name=container_name, 
        blob_name=blob_name) 
read = io.BytesIO()
download_stream = download_client.download_blob()
df = pd.read_excel(download_stream.readall())

#Make arbitrary changes: works fine
df_new = df.append(df)
print(df_new)

#Upload Blob: blob is empty
new_blob_name=f'UploadTest.xlsx'
upload_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=az_str, 
        container_name=container_name, 
        blob_name=new_blob_name)

write = io.BytesIO()
df_new.to_excel(write, sheet_name='Test Sample') 
upload_client.upload_blob(write, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by setting the stream's position to `0`. Something like:

```
write = io.BytesIO()
df_new.to_excel(write, sheet_name='Test Sample')
write.seek(0)
upload_client.upload_blob(write, blob_type="BlockBlob", overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: I have an additional question that might not be worth another post, would it be possible to do the above with an additional to_excel, for an additional sheet in the same excel book?

Comment: I would recommend asking that as a separate question please.